# Pointing a subdomain to an external server?

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, subdomain

I have a subdomain which I would like to point to a page on an external server. I am hoping I can do this without having ftp access to the external server? I can obtain access if I really HAVE to, but I'm trying to avoid it (long story). So I would love it if there is a way I can point my subdomain to a page on an external server. Redirecting is not a good option for me, as I need the page picked up in search enigines on the subdomain.

Is there any other solution besides using an iframe or php get_contents?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your options are:

1. Create a CNAME DNS record for your subdomain and have the external server handle the request to show the page you want at their end
2. Create an htaccess RewriteRule like:

   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com`
   `RewriteRule (.*) http://external.domain.com/the/page/ [R=301,L]`
3. Create a page on your subdomain that uses an iframe to show the external page

I'm not 100% sure how <strike>Google</strike> search engines treat points 2 and 3, and I'm guessing you don't want to/can't configure the external server to handle the CNAME DNS record.